# How to print single element of string array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, userdefaults

I am a beginner in swift, how do i print the single element after saving string array in UserDefaults. Below is the swift code

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = [requestModel.latitude, requestModel.longitude] //"24.7256", "46.67820"
userDefaults.set(array, forKey: "myKey")
let strings = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myKey")
print(strings[0]) // expecting to print the latitude value
```

Comment: And what's happening? Also, didn't you mean `print(strings[0])` instead?

Comment: @Larme Please check the above updated code.

Comment: What's the output? What's printed?

Comment: `let strings:[String] = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myKey") as! [String]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you read from userdefaults compilator doesn't know type of object so you need to cast it

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = [location.latitude, location.longitude] //"24.7256", "46.67820"
userDefaults.set(array, forKey: "myKey")
if let strings = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myKey") as? [Double] {
  print(strings[0])
}
```

Comment: Cast to `as? [String]`

Comment: ... or use `stringArray(forKey:`

Comment: I used double because I assume location is CLLocationCoordinate2D so latitude/longitude would be Double, but String should work fine as well